# AngularJS data-ng-hide puts blank spaces

Tags: angularjs, html

It looks as though data-ng-hide works as expected except that it puts a space where the value would be shown.  Is there a way to surpress that space so the values which should be shown are shifted to the right.  For instance my loop has three people in it, but on the third person will be shown.  The name for that person is to the far right rather than the first column on the left.  I can't use data-ng-if as it removes values from the array.

This is the code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center">Checked Out to:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-repeat="rows in chunkedData">
            <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="route in rows">
                <span data-ng-hide="!route.checkedOut">{{route.user.firstName}} {{route.user.lastName}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior: You're repeating a <div> that has the class "col-xs-4".

The ng-hide is inside it, meaning that for each route in rows, you'll display a column with or without text in it.

Try this instead :

```
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="route in rows | filter:{checkedOut:true}">
        {{route.user.firstName}} {{route.user.lastName}}
    </div>
```

[AngularJS's documentation on ngRepeat and filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) could also help you to better understand filters.

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks!